# How can I access a property with a protected setter in my asp.net-mvc controller from fluent-nhibernate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate, setter, s#arp-architecture

Using S#arp Architecture 1.0RC...

I have a controller that never seems to update one of my properties.

My class is a User abstract class with a Manager property. Manager is subclasses from User, as is Employee.

I declared the property setter for Manager as protected and provided a method to AddManager. That way, I could also control the Users that a Manager has from the collection in that entity.

My problem is that the ModelBinder doesn't locate the Manager property of the updated item on the postback. If I remove protected, it works fine. Add protected back: no soup for me.

**What portion of the following allows me to keep my setter protected and still get the value in the controller on the postback?**

Thanks...

Here's the obligatory mapping (some editing out of non-particulars):

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-access="">
  <class name="Core.User, Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="Users" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0" column="UserId">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
 <le snip..>
<many-to-one access="field.camelcase-underscore" cascade="save-update" name="Manager" column="ManagerId" />
<joined-subclass name="Core.Employee, Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
  <key column="EmployeeId" />
</joined-subclass>
<joined-subclass name="Core.Approver, Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
  <key column="ManagerId" />
  <bag name="Users" lazy="true" cascade="save-update" inverse="true">
    <key column="ManagerId" />
    <one-to-many class="Core.User, Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  </bag>
</joined-subclass>
```

My polymorphic class is

```
public abstract class User : Entity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    private Manager _manager;
    public virtual Manager Manager
    {
        get { return _manager; }
        protected set { _manager = value; }
    }

    public virtual void SetManager(Manager manager)
    {
        if (_manager != null)
        {
            _manager.RemoveUser(this);
        }
        _manager = manager;
    }

}


public class Manager : User
{
    public Manager()
    {
        _users = new List<User>();
    }

    private IList<User> _users;
    public virtual IList<User> Users
    {
        get { return _users; }
        protected set { _users = value; }
    }

    public virtual void AddUser(User user)
    {
        if (_users.Contains(user)) return;
        Users.Add(user);
        user.SetManager(this);
    }

    public virtual void RemoveUser(User user)
    {
        if (!_users.Contains(user)) return;
        Users.Remove(user);
        user.SetManager(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider use a view-model class instead of passing your domain entities to your views. You could populate your view-model class from your domain query, pass that to your view and when it comes back, in your controller re map it to your domain entity and carry on. A great tool to help you do this very thing is called AutoMapper. This may also help with other issues down the road.

[AutoMapper on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper)

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. I will give AutoMapper a look right now and report back how it worked for this... Appreciated!

Comment: This is my answer. I already see where AutoMapper will benefit me.

One note: I should have clarified that I *was* using a ViewModel class in my controller and in passing to my page -- that's the best way I know to send SelectList items that exist outside of my entity.